# Class tag don't remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML menu structure. With the following:

```
<div id="footer-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="menu-1" href="site.com/1"></a></li>
    <li><a id="menu-2" href="site.com/2"></a></li>
    <li><a id="menu-3" href="site.com/3"></a></li>
    <li><a id="menu-4" href="site.com/4"></a></li>
    <li><a id="menu-5" href="site.com/5"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And i want to add active class when on active menu. 
My JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#footer-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        // you usually want to prevent default for handling link clicks,
        // otherwise the browser follows the href (if that's intended skip this)
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#footer-menu li a').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

This function add active class, OK.

```
<li><a id="menu" href="site.com" class="active"><a>
```

But when click another link, don't remove `class` tag before.

```
<li><a id="menu" href="site.com" class><a>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Your markup in invalid. IDs must be unique, and `li` tags should be closed.

Comment: You'll need to start by writing valid HTML with unique ID's, closing elements etc.

Comment: It's sample and i edited my post.

Comment: @adeneo you're right about the "id" thing, but `<li>` elements don't need to be closed. (The `<a>` elements should be properly closed of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make your HTML markup valid since they are having duplicate IDs.
you can try this

```
$('#footer-menu a').click(function(){
     $('#footer-menu a').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: He'll still see exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to remove the "class" attribute. The browser debugger shows it to you because it's present, but as long as it doesn't have the class **value** "active", it won't hurt anything.

Comment: More exactly, an empty `class` attribute has exactly the same effect as no attribute at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="footer-menu">
<ul>
<li><a id="menu" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a id="menu" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a id="menu" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a id="menu" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a id="menu" href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#footer-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#footer-menu li a').each( function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aApYZ/1/